# Induction: base step in proving $\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-\frac12\right)^j=\frac{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3\cdot 2^n}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, induction

The other day I learn't about Induction, and though I have a good understanding of it, I have come to a problem in an assignment. To be clear I am not looking for an answer. Also the actual question is paragraph four so skip ahead if you would like...

What question is asking...: "Use induction to prove that the following equation holds for all non-negative integers n:"

Here is the question:

$$\sum_{j=0}^n\left(-\frac12\right)^j=\frac{2^{n+1}+(-1)^n}{3\cdot 2^n}$$

I did the basis step where I made $n=1$. On the left hand side the answer was $-1/2$ and on the right it is $1/2$. Is this allowed and make it true so I can continue with my proof? Though I know a negative does not equal a positive, I just thought maybe this was an exception (hopefully or I'm screwed for solving).

or should off the bat I make $n=0$ for my basis step since then it would be true? Since $1=1$.

It would also be really embarrassing if it was just a bedmas/or other mistake on my part...

Answer (score 3):

For your basis step, you need to start with $n=0$ here, since we are interested in all *non-negative* integers, and $0$ is the least of all non-negative integers.

To address your concern about the equality not holding for $n = 1$, both sides of the equation *are* positive. Recall, on the left hand side, we have a sum, which means when $n = 1$, we sum the result for $n = 0$ with the result for $n = 1$: $$\left(-\frac 12\right)^0 + \left(-\frac 12\right)^1 = 1 - \frac 12 = \frac 12$$And $\frac 12$ this is what we get when we evaluate the right-hand side at $n = 1$.

Comment: Needs more ++++ 1